# Sailsjs: Query association using blueprint API and query string

Tags: sails.js

If possible I'd like to query a related model using a query parameter rather than overwriting a blueprint action.  I'm not sure if I need to manually populate an association for this to work.

I have two related models: Idea and Tag.  An Idea can have many Tags, and a Tag can be associated with many Ideas (M-M association).  I would like to query all Ideas that are associated with a given Tag name.

I had this working in the past, but now the result is always an empty array.  I looked through my git history and I have two different possible solutions that I have used in the past

Blueprint Endpoint (worked in the past?):

- http://localhost:1337/Idea?tags.text[]=GIS
- http://localhost:1337/Idea?tags.text=GIS

Example Idea instance (other associations removed for brevity):

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "text": "GIS",
      "description": "Geographic Information Systems involves the association of location and attribute data, data collection, and analysis.",
      "approved": true,
      "createdAt": "2015-08-26T13:27:19.593Z",
      "updatedAt": "2015-08-26T13:29:44.209Z",
      "id": "55ddbeb71670cf062be4e5c0"
    }
  ],
  "title": "First Idea",
  "description": "Let's all do some more GIS!",
  "status": "Proposed",
  "createdAt": "2015-08-26T13:30:03.238Z",
  "updatedAt": "2015-08-26T13:30:03.240Z",
  "id": "55ddbf5b1670cf062be4e5c1"
}
```